# How to install coqui-ai TTS on Manjaro and use it with a simple command?

Tags: linux, manjaro, text-to-speech

Since [coqui-ai TTS](https://github.com/coqui-ai/TTS) isn't in the AUR I have to install it manually.

When I install it directly with

```
pip install TTS
```

it installs but at the end of the installation I get the error

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
typer 0.3.2 requires click<7.2.0,>=7.1.1, but you have click 8.1.3 which is incompatible.
google-api-core 2.10.0 requires protobuf<5.0.0dev,>=3.20.1, but you have protobuf 3.19.6 which is incompatible.
```

To avoid this error I think I should install it in a virtual environment, but I want to be able to use it like

```
ttst text wav
```

using a function like

```
ttst() {
  cat $1 | sentences | xargs -0 tts --model_name "tts_models/en/ljspeech/tacotron2-DDC"  --out_path "${2:-out.wav}" --text
}
```

and I don't know how to do that if I install it in a virtual environment.

If there is a simpler way just forget what I said. What I want to know is the answer to the title.

`sentences` refers to the [sentences-bin](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/sentences-bin) package, required to tokenize the text in sentences, as coqui TTS only works on sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can use [pipx](https://pypi.org/project/pipx/) for this.

```
python3 -m pip install --user pipx
python3 -m pipx ensurepath
pipx install TTS
```

Long and short sentences give errors. For long sentences `max_decoder_steps: 20000` can be added to `/home/user/.local/share/tts/tts_models--en--ljspeech--tacotron2-DDC/config.json`. Short sentences need to be removed before calling the model. Or alternatively use a script to convert each sentence on it's own and then concatenate all the audio outputs. Like [sapo](https://gitlab.com/christosangel/sapo) or [this one](https://lemmy.ml/post/563494)